# MySql replace function - find specific string with whitespace at start and end

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to replace all the instances of ' st ' in my address column with ' street '. Here is what I have.

```
update donor
set Address_Street = replace(Address_Street, ‘ ST ’, ‘ Street ’);
```

I get an error executing because of the whitespace before and after the strings i'm trying to search and replace with. I want a space before and after each to make sure I don't replace a street name with this change. Example( 5 Stanford lane get changed to 5 Streetandfor lane)

Why is MySql not happy with searching for the whitespace before and after? Am I missing a simple syntax rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have weird curly quotes instead of normal quotes. Try this:

```
update donor
set Address_Street = replace(Address_Street, ' ST ', ' Street ');
```

Comment: So weird I don't get how those quotes got in there like that. I typed it in like every other query I do but sure enough that was it. I wonder how I got those weird ones? THANKS THOUGH!